# Unable To query use realm

Tags: android, realm, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

I am using Realm along with RxJava and at the end i want to fetch an observable that i can use:

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Data>> getData_List() {
    final Observable<RealmResults<Data>> observable 
                               = realm.where(Data.class).findAll().asObservable();
}
```

This is my current code, as of now i get an error saying that they are incompatible types, ie **observable** is `io.reactivex.Observable` whereas what the Realm returns is of type `rx.Observable<io.realm.RealmResults<E>>`.

What i want to do is query the realm database and return an Observable list of data objects (`Observable<List<Data>>`).

How can i do this?

Comment: AsObservable returns type for RxJava1

Answer (score 1):

`asObservable()` method returns RxJava1.x types and has been deprecated. Since you are using RxJava2, types don't match. See [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4135) github issue for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert RxJava1 Observable into RxJava2 Observable, you can use [RxJava2Interop](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Interop) library using `RxJavaInterop.toV2Flowable(rx.Observable);`.

Comment: Can you help me with this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060003/speed-of-search-operation-in-a-realm-database

Answer (score -1):

You can use toList() operator to achieve this. RealmResults are just the cursor or pointer to the database and they cannot be used as list directly. Follow this blog if you want to know more about toList.

http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2015/11/rxjava-operators-tolist.html